# PL/SQL Developer Command Window executes host command asynchronously (unwanted)

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, plsqldeveloper

(PL/SQL Developer 9.0.6 & Oracle Server 11.2.0.3)

From a Command Window when using host command to shell out and execute something, the script does not wait for the return of the shell as it would if I were using SQL*Plus.

```
create table mytable (
...
;
host impdp /@mydb SCHEMAS=myschema NETWORK_LINK=mydblink CONTENT=data_only
create table mytable2 (
...
;
```

I want the data pump import to finish before before proceeding to execute creating mytable2.

My current hack is to put a dummy `accept` after the host command to pause the script. I want to eliminate the unnecessary hack.

Is there a setting in PL/SQL Developer to make the Command Window behavior consistent with SQL*Plus in this regard?

Comment: Thanks Stack Overflow for giving me the Tumbleweed badge. Humiliating new users seems like a fine idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this feature does not exist.  See [this thread](http://forums.allroundautomations.com/ubb/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=44645) on the Allround Automations forum where someone else had the same problem.  The response was "We'll try to enhance this."

You may want to reply to that thread, so they know that the feature would help more than one person.  Not every feature request gets implemented, but the company does appear to pay attention to anything posted on their forums.